# Is the ColdFusion ColdFire project dead?

Tags: firefox, coldfusion, firebug, coldfire

http://coldfire.riaforge.org/

I can't get the current version (1.9.207.249) to work in with Firefox 14.0.1 with Firebug 1.10.2.

I assume it is broken because the plugin has not been updated for the release of Firebug 1.10.

Has anyone got it working with these settings?

Comment: The only people that can answer that are the project maintainers. [Ask _them_](http://coldfire.riaforge.org/index.cfm?event=page.projectcontact) and/or [raise an issue](https://github.com/nmische/ColdFire/issues).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A new version of ColdFire was released that should work with Firefox 15/Firebug 1.10.

https://github.com/nmische/ColdFire/downloads

Comment: BTW the redirect to the project page on github that you see when clicking the "Download Project" link on the ColdFire homepage on riaforge doesn't work in Firefox 15.0.1, lol. It does work when using Google Chrome though.

Comment: Glad the update is working for you. The riaforge download link works for me using Firefox 15.0.1 on OSX so I'm not sure what is going on there.

Answer (score 2):

Based on this I will assume it's still alive.  Perhaps try the Chrome version?

http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2012/8/24/First-release-of-ColdFire-for-Chrome

Comment: That's right Paul, Ray currently working on chrome based. So definitely it's not dead.